# Is there a way to clean up the dataframe like this?

Tags: r

So, there is no specific data I am currently working, but I am just curious about this kind of problem.

Let's assume my dataframe looks like this:

```
Name                  Number                   Sum
What (feat.Drake)      1A                      100
What                   1A                      100
What (Radio Edit)      1A                      100
What (I Remix)         1B                      200
What (Remastered)      1B                      200
```

This turns into:

```
Name                  Number                   Sum
What (feat.Drake)      1A                      300
What (I Remix)         1B                      400
```

So, what I tried to do there is to sum up the Sum by Number. However, Name cannot be removed, so I kept the first Name that appeared on the dataframe.

Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>%
    group_by(Number) %>%
    summarise(Name = first(Name), Sum = sum(Sum))    
 #  Number              Name   Sum     
 #   <chr>             <chr> <int>
 #1     1A What (feat.Drake)   300
 #2     1B    What (I Remix)   400
```

Comment: ah, this is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R method. It's a bit more wordy, but works:

```
cbind("Name"=df$Name[!duplicated(df$Number)], aggregate(Sum ~ Number, data=df, sum))
               name Number Sum
1 What_(feat.Drake)     1A 300
2    What_(I_Remix)     1B 400
```

As usual, `aggregate` gets the sum by group. The first name by group is identified by `duplicated` and is extracted using subsetting `[`. These results are combined with `cbind`. As a final touch, I added the Name variable name back within `cbind`.